# PaperTrail and showing a single activity by the id of an activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using the gem PaperTrail. On "index" it shows the latest activities of all the models. I want to create the page "show" where I can see a single activity fetched by id. However, how can I fetch it by id? What's really id in PaperTrail? Does every model have its own id? Or is it shared between all the models?

In other words, how should I go about creating a page "show" for showing a single activity?

I think id in PaperTrail in the way I want it is a combination of a model name and its version, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Update history table to polymorphic save history of all models.

So, now using model class name and id you can get data of specified model.